# increase performances of CPU-intensive PHP scripts

Tags: php, c, performance

I have a PHP script which takes hours (maybe days) to execute. It is quite simple but very CPU-intensive, most of the execution time is spent into (I can tell after having profiled the script):

1. `$array = explode(',', $a[$i]);`
   where `$a[$i]` is a very long string which represents a vector of 30k elements separated by comma
2. `foreach($array as $key => $value)` loops; where for each loop some in_array() and comparison and assignment operations are performed

`$a` is actually a very large and sparse matrix (30k * 30k) but I can't keep it in memory (8GB seems to be not enough RAM) so I keep just a "sparse representation" (basically each row is a string) and use `explode()` any time I need to work on a row.

I know that rewriting everything in C (or other languages) would improve performances (how much?) but, before doing that I would like to know if I can do anything to improve the execution time in PHP.

EDIT after answers.

I tried several of your advises and here is my report:

1) str_getcsv is in most of the case slower than explode

2) SPLFixedArray decrease the memory requested to store the matrix but still, 8GB was not enough for a 30k x 30k matrix so I don't think it can help much; the real problem here is the lack of a sparse representation for matrix in PHP I think

3) I can't store all the results of the explode operations because, still, that would mean keeping the whole matrix in memory (not enough RAM)

4) I've tried the database approach even if I was sure it would have been slower: I've stored triples (i,j,value) to represent each matrix element; even deleting the less important values (I can sacrifice values less than a threshold and get a less precise result, but still useful) and storing just 18 millions tuples, the approach with mysql myisam is much slower than my array approach in memory.

5) I've tried the database approach using the MEMORY engine (a mysql table in RAM) and storing all the matrix elements except the ones having value zero; having 42 millions records this time...it is faster, not an order of magnitude but 2-4 times faster...I think I can finish the job in 5 days instead of 15-20...it is still too much (I would like to finish in 24 hours), if you have any other suggestions you are very welcome

EDIT 2: I explain the problem

I'll give some details about the problem, I really need to simplify everything otherwise it would be too long to explain but I think it is enough to understand better the situation.

I have a matrix representing distances among nodes; the distance in an integer and could also be infinite.

I have a memory table representing each distance with triples: node_1, node_2, distance (just the non infinite distances are represented).

I have this sort of greedy algorithm that I did not write and I should optimize to execute it in a feasible time (let's say less than one day) on a laptop having 8GB of RAM.

The algo basically gets in input two nodes and designs a path between a starting node and an ending node step by step according to the following two properties that must be verified at each step:

- the new intermediate node must be chosen among the set of nodes that are closer to the ending node respect to the current node
- among those nodes, the one which is the closer to the current node is chosen

Please consider that
1) The triangle inequality is NOT satisfied.
2) It is NOT a shortest path problem

Here is some pseudo code for the function I call several times until I'm close enough to the ending node:

```
get_next_node($node_1, $node_2){

    $dist = select distance from distances_table where node_2 = $node_2 and node_1 = $node_1

    $candidates_ar = select node_1 from distances_table where node_2 = $node_2 and distance < $dist

    $distances_ar = select distance from distances_table where node_1 = $node_1 and node_2 in ($candidates_ar) // e.g. $distances_ar[12] contains distance between node 12 and $node_1

    $min = 1000;
    foreach ($candidates_ar as $value){
        if ($distances_ar[$value] < $min){
            $min = $distances_ar[$value]
            $next_node = $value
        }
    }

}
```

I have omitted a lot of checks and additional complexity, but this is the basic and this is where the algo spends most of time.

I guess it can be solved with an implementation of A* but I would like to avoid it if it is possible to increase the performances so that I can execute it in hours (not days).

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps try using str_getcsv() instead of explode()

Comment: if I understand it correctly, each time you need a row, you do an explode. do it only once, and store the results. regarding C: I'm pretty sure it will improve performance a lot...

Comment: use index data structures, like in a database, or even better: use a database

Comment: But try using SPLFixedArray because they're faster and more memory efficient than simply enumaerated arrays

Comment: if you want to completely botcher the performance, yes, database is the way to go...

Comment: If you're doing advanced matrix pure maths surely you would be better in matlab? Failing that rewriting to C or C++ would increase the speed exponentially and allow you to thread the calculations if you want.  Depending on what your doing/planning on doing with the matrix data perhaps http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmatrixlib/ may help you a little.

Comment: Reimplementing it in C might be slightly faster, but not of several orders of magnitudes so that it finishes in minutes instead of days. What exactly are you doing with the data in the sparse matrix? Maybe there is a more efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: Would `array_walk()` be faster than a `foreach()` here?

Comment: `in_array()` is very slow, if you are able to safely flip the array using `array_flip` then you can check if a value exists with `isset()`. This is way faster especially when the array becomes bigger. [Small demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11078901). If you could post the code with some input, I could maybe take a look into improving it.

Comment: I have edited the question explaining the underlying problem and the main algorithm used.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `A*`? That last sentence makes no sense...

Comment: Additionally, what takes *days* to run? Finding the next node? Or resolving the entire graph?

Comment: @ircmaxell A*: because we have an urgence to complete this task and not much time to test different approaches, that's why I would prefer to optimize the current one if there is room for improvement.
Resolving the entire graph should take a few days right now.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, you've got a performance problem. Now the fun part begins.

The first step, is **don't guess**. Don't start rewriting in C. Don't switch PHP compilers. That's for suckers. Instead, start by trying to find the actual bottlenecks.

Get XDEBUG and generate a [cachegrind profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) of the application. This will show you where the majority of the time is spent.

You can also use [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php).

The point is, don't guess, but profile. Find the slow parts of the algorithms, and then work to optimize them.

The problem is likely not the code, but the algorithm that you're using. I'd suggest trying to formalize the algorithm, so that you can then try to optimize and tweak parts for your specific constraints.

For example. Right now, you're parsing large CSV strings. Why? Why not stick that in a database and let the database do the heavy lifting for you? Obviously it may not be possible with your specific use-case, but whenever I see people operating on arrays of 30k elements in PHP, typically that's because they are doing something they shouldn't be in the first place.

And if all else fails, try to chunk the algorithm so that you can run it in parts. That way you can try to do a map-reduce or similar technique to tweak runtime.

In short, it **really** depends on what exactly you're doing. But re-coding or switching runtimes would be my *last* resort, not the first step...

Comment: I already profiled the script and the explode and foreach loop were the bottlenecks. About the database approach, I've edited the question to add my report on it.

Comment: @Eugenio: Foreach is *not* your bottleneck. The bottleneck would be your algorithm. And that's why I suggested formalizing it so that you could tune it better. Or simply restructure the algorithm to operate more efficiently.

Comment: Additionally, downvoters, what more can be said given the complete lack of information around what the OP is trying to do? He has an algorithm problem. You don't solve an algorithm problem by moving to C. You solve it by refactoring the algorithm. Sure, there comes a time where porting to C or other runtimes is an option, but that's not the first step (as it will not give you orders of magnitude gains). So unless the OP posts an actual algorithm, this answer is the best way to help him. It is the only answer that can possible give the order-of-magnitude changes he's after.

Comment: I have edited the question explaining the underlying problem and the main algorithm used.

Comment: For me, doing calculations in PHP which takes days in simply stupid. That's for suckers. C will give at least 1 or 2 order of magnitude peformance boost. and yes, obviously, if it's possible, you also want to use an algorithm with a better asymptotic complexity. But PHP is definitely the wrong tool for this job. C/C++, fortran, F#, python with numpy, haskell... plenty of good languages out there for the job.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Doing calculations which takes days is stupid enough on its own. PHP likely is the wrong tool for the job. That doesn't mean switching tools is a valid first step. The algorithm is borked, that much is clear. Switching tools without fixing the algorithm isn't going to gain nearly enough. Instead, since there's already a working implementation here, start refining it and getting it to a better place. And *then* consider switching languages. But to switch when the algorithm is still borked is a bit blind if you ask me...

Answer (score -1):

Have you heard about Facebook hiphop compiler. You can try [this](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php). 
 Its helps to execute your script much faster and take minimum cpu recourse.

Comment: Yeah, no. Replacing a runtime will not get you an exponential increase in performance. Hiphop may be faster, but it's not a magical pill. In fact for most use-cases, hiphop will cost you more to implement than you'll save due to the extra developer and sys-admin time it will consume. Facebook wrote it because they have the scale to justify it. The *vast* majority of other sites do not...

Answer (score -2):

Rewriting it in C would be a lot faster!

You can use `str_getcsv($a[$i]);` instead which would be a bit faster.

Regarding RAM, do what you want with the data and the use `unset($a[$i])` as you go along.

So either rewrite in C, or you could make it go in stages, split the CSV into 10 chunks and process it that way, you could even run all 10 at the same time which may increase speed. Or have your CSV file in a database to really cut down on speed.

Comment: Simply rewriting it in C does not guarantee that it will go faster. The problem is more likely to lie in the volume of data; i.e. the I/O and in how complex the processing is.

Comment: This looks like a CPU intensive matrix calculation. Just by knowing how the two languages store the basic data structures I would expect at least an order of magnitude improvement with C.